# Codeigniter error Message: Missing argument 1 for mtree::insert_to_righ

Tags: php, codeigniter

i got this error message while running my Php codeigniter project :

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Missing argument 1 for mtree::insert_to_right(), called in
>   C:\AppServ\www\News\application\controllers\bcontroller.php on line 20
>   and defined
>
> Filename: models/mtree.php
>
> Line Number: 28

this  is my model function :

```
    function insert_to_right($row, $direct_id) {
            $left_parent = $this->get_right_parent($direct_id);
            $row->members_direct_id = $left_parent;
            $this->db->insert('table1', $row);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO table2 (child, parent)
            VALUES (" . $this->db->escape($row->members_id) . ", " . $this->db->escape($left_parent) . ")";
            $this->db->query($sql);
        }
 function get_right_parent($id) {

        return $id;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your controller where it's calling this method?

Comment: i'm just call it                                                     `function index { $this->mtree->insert_to_right();}`

Comment: You need to pass in something to the `insert_to_right('data', 'parent');` so that they can be inserted. Right now you're pretty much just calling the function without any arguments, thats what the error is about.

Comment: i pass this arguments when i calling the function on controller `$this->mtree->insert_to_right('members_id','members_direct_id ');` but it still respond with another error `Message: Attempt to assign property of non-object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the function `insert_to_right($row, $direct_id)` requires two arguments, either you can pass in those two variables when you call them, or you can assign default values for it like `insert_to_right($row = '....', $direct_id = '...')`. I don't think you can just pass in any default variable as this would insert it into the database, so I would recommend you pass in the argument from the controller.

Comment: i did but i got another error `Message: Attempt to assign property of non-object`